# Add start and reset function to button

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm new in coding and trying to figure out exercises on my own. I've done sort of scratch exercise where you can draw with mousemove function. Problem is: I would like to have two buttons on my page,

- one will be start button where my function will be executed, not as soon as I'm on my page.
- The second one will be the reset button which will clear the page.

I've been on this exercise for a while and still couldn't make it work and I would appreciate any sort of help. Thanks a lot.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    section {

        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;

    }
    .buttons {

    }

    button:nth-child(1) {
        margin: 20px;
    }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>

    <div id="buttons">

        <button id="start">Start</button>
        <button id="reset">Clear</button>
    </div>

   </section>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const section = document.querySelector("section");
const startClick = document.getElementById("start");
const resetClick = document.getElementById("reset");





section.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  const circle = document.createElement("div");
  section.appendChild(circle);
  circle.style.height = "20px";
  circle.style.width = "20px";
  circle.style.borderRadius = "50%";
  circle.style.position = "absolute";
  circle.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
  circle.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
  circle.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}); 



resetClick.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e = section;
  section.removeEventListener();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) need a two argument to execute function please read the document or else see you console .
2. And also you clear button id was mismatched .

**Updated**

```js
const section = document.querySelector("section");
const startClick = document.getElementById("start");
const resetClick = document.getElementById("reset");

function appender(e) {
  const circle = document.createElement("div");
  circle.className='appender';
  section.appendChild(circle);
  circle.style.height = "20px";
  circle.style.width = "20px";
  circle.style.borderRadius = "50%";
  circle.style.position = "absolute";
  circle.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
  circle.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
  circle.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}

startClick.addEventListener("click", e => {
  section.addEventListener("mousemove", appender);
})

section.addEventListener("mousemove", appender);

resetClick.addEventListener("click", e => {
  section.removeEventListener('mousemove', appender);
  document.querySelectorAll('.appender').forEach(a=> a.remove())
})
```

```html
<section>

  <div id="buttons">

    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="reset">Clear</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the warning, now I can remove the event listener with this way but still doesn't do what I want. It simply stops executing my function anymore but doesn't clear the page yet.

Comment: That works pretty well now. Thank you very much for your help and saving me going more crazy  :)